# Magento Attribute-Codes with Uppercase Letters need to work

Tags: csv, magento, magento2, uppercase, magento2.4

Hello Guys,

is there any possibility to make the Magento 2 Import-Module uppercase insensitive?

I have attribute-codes like "ColorName" or "BaseColor" and I need them to be working. Right now the data in CSV-File is ignored by Magento for those attributes. The Problem is: I can not change them. There is too much code already written. So i really need magento to recognize uppercase attribute-codes. There is no other solution.

But, is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but the attribute code is comverted to lowercase in `Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::retrieveAttributeByCode`.
the method looks like this

```
/**
 * Retrieve attribute by code
 *
 * @param string $attrCode
 * @return mixed
 */
public function retrieveAttributeByCode($attrCode)
{
    /** @var string $attrCode */
    $attrCode = mb_strtolower($attrCode);

    if (!isset($this->_attributeCache[$attrCode])) {
        $this->_attributeCache[$attrCode] = $this->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode);
    }

    return $this->_attributeCache[$attrCode];
}
```

you can try to override the method and remove the `$attrCode = mb_strtolower($attrCode);` line or create an `around` plugin for it.